# Is it possible to annotate data models with metadata in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata

I have a simple data model, that i want to annotate with metadata

```
export class Certification {
    title: string;
    certificationType?: CertificationType;
    validTo?: number;
    description?: string;
    externalIdentifier: Guid;

    constructor() {
        this.title = '';
        this.certificationType = CertificationType.Undefined;
        this.validTo = 0;
        this.description = '';
        this.externalIdentifier = null;
    }
}
```

I was hoping i could somehow annotate the model like so

```
export class Certification {
    @Heading() 
    title: string;
    certificationType?: CertificationType;
    @Label('My label') 
    validTo?: number;
    description?: string;
    @Hidden()
    externalIdentifier: Guid;

    constructor() {...}
}
```

I have a lot of these very similar models, so i would prefer to create a simple component to handle display logic for all of them, rather than one component for each model and the the difference is then controlled by each individual template.

I have tried to use the reflect-metadata api as defined in the typescript documentation as described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators
But even though metadata is applied to the model at construction time they seem to be lost when i have assigned it through binding.

```
<display-annotated-model [model]="certification"></display-annotated-model>
```

So my question is have any one got this working?

Or is there a different method to annotate data models that i should look at (I have exhausted my googling abilities)?

I need to get this working in Angular 9. Any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. The original plan for annotations would have made this very useful. Unfortunately these annotation became decorators. As decorators any metadata about the property they are decorating is stored in a global decorator store.

Angular itself converts its built in decorators (@Component(), @Directive(), @Pipe(), NgModel(), @Injectable(), etc...) at compile time back into annotations.

What is the difference between annotations and decorators?

Annotations are just metadata, and stored on the instance of the object (depending on what you are annotating).

Decorators are wrappers that may modify the property accessor, method, class -- as well as provide metadata on each property accessor, method or class.

Because of this dynamic nature of decorators, compilers cannot tell if the underlying code can be safely tree shaken.

For this reason, decorators are not suitable for browser code for most cases. Though custom compiler plugins can be created for custom decorators -- which would do essentially what Angular does for its decorators.

An alternative approach I would be interested in is being able to add the metadata do a ReactiveForm declaration.

Here is an example of something similar: https://github.com/martinmcwhorter/modelmetadata

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your explanation. I had hoped to evolve it to reactive form models too when my current use as display annotations succeeds. But are you saying the the code actually works in the repo you linked to? Then i must have a bug. Because my code looks very similar, but a main difference is that i am trying to use a pipe on the model to handle the annotations. So maybe that is where the reference is lost somehow(is the pipe working on a different instance of the model i wonder), so when i use `Reflect.getMetadata` i get `undefined`.

Comment: Or is it because i have typed instances? i see you use `: any`

Comment: Ok, i found the bug. I had somehow managed to instantiate  a Certification object and then overwrite that instance with the json object that was supposed to be mapped. So i saw the constructor be called and could verify that the metadata was written, but when i tried to read it back it was on another object (that had the same properties of course). That was my error... Thanks. I'll mark your reply as the answer as you repo link prowed that it could be done.